# Reading the page source inside <form> of a web page

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup, htmlunit

Can any one help me to read the page source present inside the  tag.

I have tried with htmlUnit and jsoup... but it retrns only the contents inside  and  tags.
Any responce is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `element.html()` to read the HTML and not the contain of tag itself in [JSoup](http://jsoup.org)

**For Example:**

```
String html = "<p>An </p><form action="SOMESERVLET"><b>example</b></form> ";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
String htmlContent = doc.select("form").first().html();
```

For your case

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("example.com").get(); 
Iterator<Element> itr = doc.select("form").iterator()
while(itr.hasNext()){ 
   Element element = itr.next();
   System.out.println(element.html());
}
```

Comment: Only one form tag is returned, if there are multiple form tags.

Comment: [`doc.select(...)`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select%28java.lang.String%29) returns `Elements` you can iterate over it to get multiple forms from the  `document`

Comment: `<form> href='http://example.com/'>` is definitely malformed HTML syntax. I edited your post to fix it.

Comment: Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com").timeout(0).get();
System.out.println(doc.toString());
I use the above code to get all the content returned by the doc. But there is a huge difference between the output and the view source (When i right click and see the view source).

Comment: @Jigar: Thanks, from your code, i came to know few details.
The problem is, the page is having a button, so when i click that button, the correct page will appear.
Is there any way the button can be clicked (event) from JAVA code itself.

Answer (score 0):

Step by step

- read html from url to string
- find `<form>` tag it is `start index`
- find `</form>` tag it is `last index`, **if this tag is not present last index is length
  **
- and just `substring` from `start` to `end` index

it is simple algorithm but I think there are a lot of tools that can help you!!!

Comment: Thank you.
I tried, the problem here is. The page consists of a lot of form tags, but only one form tag is returned.
Also,the contents inside <thead> tags are not returned.

Comment: Just firstIndexOF and lastIndex of methods help you to returm all content between first and last form tags

Comment: Document doc = Jsoup.connect("example.com").timeout(0).get(); System.out.println(doc.toString()); I use the above code to get all the content returned by the doc. But there is a huge difference between the output and the view source (When i right click and see the view source).